# "invalid literal for int()" parsing a string with space-separated numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program I'm writing for an online course is to identify whether a list of integers is positive, and then if they are check if they're palindromic. If all the conditions are true I'm supposed to print True and if they're all false I'm supposed to print false.

I have already tried using list comprehension to avoid using the map function, but it was still giving me the same error so I decided to go back to using map instead.

```
_ = input()
number = list(map(int, input()))
if all(number) > 0:
    all(number == number[::-1] for i in number)
else:
    print("False")
```

I expected `False` since the custom input I put in was:
3
8 -12 25
but instead, have been getting the error message:
ValueError: invalid literal for int 
and that line it is pointing out is line 2

Comment: If your input is numbers separated by spaces, use `split()`, e.g. `numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: Are you entering exactly the characters "3 8 - 12 25"? If you're expecting `map` to return `[3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 25]`, `int` isn't smart enough to recognize that you want hyphen to represent a range of numbers. You'll have to write your own logic for that.

Comment: `all(number) > 0` does not in fact test whether all numbers in the list are positive. For that you'd need `all(n > 0 for n in number)`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixes:

1. Splitting the numbers into a list
2. Fixing usage of `all`
3. Actually printing True in case conditions match

please let me know if this works for you:

```py
_ = input()
numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
if all(n > 0 for n in numbers) and numbers == numbers[::-1]:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your string in order to get a list from it:

```py
number = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

map() take the input string 1 char at a time - so when it hits a space (' ') - it can't be converted, try

```
number = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

instead :)